Why html files are being opened by Telegram Desktop?
Opening any HTML file, triggers Telegram as the application associated:
$ xdg-open sys.html ; ps aux | grep html
myuser+  686347  0.0  0.0 1090016 12224 pts/6   Rl   16:04   0:00 /snap/bin/telegram-desktop -- /home/myuser/sys.html
myuser+  686353  0.0  0.0  12608  2624 pts/6    S+   16:04   0:00 grep --color=auto html
$ libpxbackend-1.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/myuser/snap/telegram-desktop/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so
Gtk-Message: 16:04:44.806: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 16:04:44.806: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
[ALSOFT] (EE) Failed to connect PipeWire event context (errno: 112)
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QWidget::render: Cannot render with an inactive painter
qt.svg: Error while inflating gzip file: SVG format check failed
qt.svg: Error while inflating gzip file: SVG format check failed
qt.svg: Error while inflating gzip file: SVG format check failed

Also detected with Jupyter Notebooks, clicking on the link available after running  jupyter notebook:
$ ps aux | grep [t]elegram
myuser+  702447 69.7  3.2 1736772 505412 ?      SLl  16:27   0:02 /snap/telegram-desktop/6117/usr/bin/telegram-desktop -- /home/myuser/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-695403-open.html


Firefox is the application associated with .html files on /etc/gnome/defaults.list:
$ grep html /etc/gnome/defaults.list
application/xhtml+xml=firefox.desktop
text/html=firefox.desktop

Funny that, Brave is the default Web Browser so, I'm not assure about the effect of MIME type association at /etc/gnome/defaults.list:

Where in the OS is the effective MIME type association that is determining Telegram Desktop as the default application for opening text/html files?

~/.config/mimeapps.list, contains two sections:

Added Associations
Default Applications

Somehow, Telegram Desktop installation (v 5.4.1) via SNAP, defines it as the default app for opening text/html files:
$ grep -B 4 'text/html' ~/.config/mimeapps.list
[Added Associations]
image/png=shotwell-viewer.desktop;pinta.desktop;krita_krita.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/http=brave_brave.desktop;firefox.desktop;
application/xhtml+xml=brave_brave.desktop;
text/html=brave_brave.desktop;firefox.desktop;
--

[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/http=brave-browser.desktop
application/xhtml+xml=firefox.desktop
text/html=telegram-desktop_telegram-desktop.desktop


Just changing the text/html key on [Default Applications] section to brave-browser.desktop, will do the trick.
